# .NET Core Controller Class. Calling IConfiguration GetConnectionString in declaration throws compile error

Tags: .net, .net-core

Why is this code giving error? Is there any workaround? I need to set my public string ODataBaseAPIUrl variable with the connection string in the configuration, so I can use it in any method in my controller class.

```
namespace AlioPosApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PosFunctionsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
        public PosFunctionsController(IConfiguration config)
        {
            this.configuration = config;

        }
//THIS NEXT LINE HAS A //COMPILE ERROR!!
//"cannot reference PosFunctionsController.configuration"
        public string ODataBaseAPIUrl = configuration.GetConnectionString("ODataBaseAPIUrl"); 
...
```

This are the contents of appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ODataBaseAPIUrl" : "http://localhost:7048/DynamicsNAV110/api/beta/companies(kj4081cc-de07-41f9-9f7a-6acdaf296fa4)/"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields are initialised *before* constructors run, that's why you can't use `configuration`

You can either initialise the value inside your constructor:

```
public PosFunctionsController(IConfiguration config)
{
    this.configuration = config;
    ODataBaseAPIUrl = configuration.GetConnectionString("ODataBaseAPIUrl");
}
```

Or change the field so it isn't initialised but gets the value on every call:

```
public string ODataBaseAPIUrl => configuration.GetConnectionString("ODataBaseAPIUrl");
```

Answer (score 2):

fix your code like below.

you cannot do assignment like that. You need to make it inside your contructor by dependency injection

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PosFunctionsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    private readonly string oDataBaseAPIUrl;
    public PosFunctionsController(IConfiguration config)
    {
        this.configuration = config;
        this.oDataBaseAPIUrl = configuration.GetConnectionString("ODataBaseAPIUrl");
    }
```